# Votes + Accepted answer not matching increase in reputation

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

My answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512361/stringbuilder-comparison-returns-wrong-result/47512368#47512368) got 11 up votes and answer was accepted.

So change in reputation should be ((11 * 10) + 15) = 125. But in notification it shows 115.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes it's a bug, something is off with the top bar reputation change.